# objects of singleton class has different id in python

Tags: python, singleton

I want to maintain a unique object of some class which is complex, so I search some singleton implements with google.

but when I create many objects of this singleton class in both of 2 process, and find something illogical。

I have tried many singleton implements, one example:

```py
import sys
from  multiprocessing import Pool

class Singleton(object):
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self._cls = cls
        self._instance = {}
    def __call__(self):
        if self._cls not in self._instance:
            self._instance[self._cls] = self._cls()
        return self._instance[self._cls]

@Singleton
class frame_feature_extractor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


def func(idx_process):
    for idx in range(5):
        e = frame_feature_extractor()
        print('%d th object  in %d th process, id = %d' % (idx_process, idx, id(e)))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    #func(2)
    num_process = 2
    pool = Pool(num_process)
    for idx_process in range(num_process):
        print idx_process
        pool.apply_async(func, [idx_process])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I run this code in mac pro(python version is 2.7.15) many times, all object id are same,  the output as follow:

```sh
0 th object  in 0 th process, id = 4509630096
0 th object  in 1 th process, id = 4509630096
0 th object  in 2 th process, id = 4509630096
0 th object  in 3 th process, id = 4509630096
0 th object  in 4 th process, id = 4509630096
1 th object  in 0 th process, id = 4509630096
1 th object  in 1 th process, id = 4509630096
1 th object  in 2 th process, id = 4509630096
1 th object  in 3 th process, id = 4509630096
1 th object  in 4 th process, id = 4509630096
```

then I run this code in centos (python version is 2.7.5), objects in different process have different id, but objects in same process have same id,  the output as follow:

```sh
0 th object  in 0 th process, id = 140449211456784
0 th object  in 1 th process, id = 140449211456784
0 th object  in 2 th process, id = 140449211456784
0 th object  in 3 th process, id = 140449211456784
0 th object  in 4 th process, id = 140449211456784
1 th object  in 0 th process, id = 140449211456912
1 th object  in 1 th process, id = 140449211456912
1 th object  in 2 th process, id = 140449211456912
1 th object  in 3 th process, id = 140449211456912
1 th object  in 4 th process, id = 140449211456912
```

Also, I have tried on ubuntu 18.04, the result as on centos, it's been bothering me for a long time.

the actual application scenarios is: this object need to occupy too much GPU memory, so I need to singleton guarantee。

Answer (score 1):

You may try with [handy-decorators](https://pypi.org/project/handy-decorators/).

There's a `singleton` decorator which may help you.